# (Unity) How can I save all of the Options that i've added dynamically to a dropdown?

Tags: unity-game-engine, save, dropdown

In Unity I have created an input field and buttons that dynamically add/remove Options to a Dropdown menu while the program is running. How can I save all of the Dropdown Options when I close the program, so that I can load the Options on next start up? To clarify, I don't need to save the Dropdown Option that is selected, I need to save all of the available Options.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just saving strings, it's pretty easy and there are a few options.

If there are only a few, you could use [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html)

If there are more than a few, or you want to let the player edit them, save them to a text file in the [StreamingAssets](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html) folder using [JSONUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html). If you want to save images, you'd probably save them to the same place but the process would just be a bit more complicated to make sure you save the images along with the strings.

More info about saving persistent data between sessions [here](https://learn.unity.com/project/saving-persistent-player-data-in-unity).

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'll check out the information you provided!